# web config errorMode

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, custom-errors, http-error

Hey guys I am kind of new to all of this so this might be a simple question but I want some clarification on this topic. I have a website and when an Http error occurs I send people to a customized page this works perfectly. The only issue is that it is also sending me to that customized page. I would like it so that I can see detailed errors on the production server (reason is that sometimes error pop up in production server and not in the development server) and send everyone else to the customized page  this last part is done the first part I am having trouble with this is what I have in my web.config

```
  <system.web>
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />
  <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />

      <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly">
  <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
  //this is working
  <error statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="~/myerrors" responseMode="file" />
</httpErrors>
```

and my last question is how would the production server know that your LocalHost?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you're confusing terminology here, so I'll try and clarify.

A connection from "localhost", in this context, means that you are connecting to the website from the same computer that the site is running on. This can happen if you're developing it on your local machine, or if you've used remote desktop to connect directly to the server and are browsing the site from that session.

If you are on your own machine connecting to your production server, you are no longer "localhost" - you are Joe Bloggs out on the Internet, the same as every other user, and you will get the same error page.

I would suggest adding additional functionality to the customised error page to pick up who is accessing it (if you are authenticating users), or using an external component such as ELMAH to help you with your error logging.

Comment: Oh ok i see so what your saying is something like logging; if a user arrives at my customized error page to log the error and how it occurred .

Comment: Yes. Users are odd beasts, they're capable of breaking things in the most interesting ways that the rest of us can only dream of. They'll find errors that you may miss simply due to the way they use the site.